# Get focused scene value

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm using macOS Monterey Beta 4 along with Xcode 13 Beta 4, and I'm trying to share information from the currently focused `Scene` to my apps menu (`CommandGroup`).

To do this, I'm using the new `focusedSceneValue` [function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/focusedscenevalue%28_%3A_%3A%29). However, it doesn't seem to work.

App file:

```
struct ActionKey: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = () -> Void
}
extension FocusedValues {
    var action: (() -> Void)? {
        get { self[ActionKey.self] }
        set { self[ActionKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct TestCommands: Commands {
    @FocusedValue(\.action) var action
    
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
            Button(action: {
                action?()
            }) {
                Text("Test menu item")
            }
            .disabled(action == nil) // This is always nil
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            TestCommands()
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .focusedSceneValue(\.action) {
                print("Clicked!")
            }
    }
}
```

Most of the code is copied from the documentation, however the menu item is always disabled, because `action` is always nil (its never set by `FocusedValue`).

I thought `focusedSceneValue` would work regardless of what `View` is focused (as stated in the documentation).

Is there anything I am doing wrong?
Any help would be awesome.

Comment: I tried to use `@FocusedValue`/`@FocusedState` in beta 3 for a macOS app but couldn’t get it to work so maybe this is still the case.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Oh well :( I really hope apple fixes this soon